# Life of an instance retrieved from Hibernate Session in HttpSession

Tags: hibernate, servlets, httpsession

I ll explain my problem with an example. In my JSP login page , each correct login puts an instance of an Object called 'User' which keeps data of the user logging into the HttpSession(`session.setAttribute("user",userObject)`).How that object is created is, that user's username and password are checked and an instance('User') of User object is retrieved from HibernateSession.
In another page, when I retrieve above set userObject from HttpSession, the object can be retrieved without error. But when its methods are called, it gives an exception `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session`  .Why I cannot that userObject from HttpSession even though I have put it earlier?

Why an empty object(instance variable have no values) exists in HttpSession even though the object had values earlier when it add to the session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can happen if the `User` entity has a collection property which is lazily fetched. The collection will then only be actually filled with the data from the DB when the caller actually needs to access it by e.g. `size()`, `iterator()`, etc. This needs to happen within the very same Hibernate session as when the `User` is been retrieved. In a properly designed webapplication the Hibernate session has namely a lifespan of exactly one HTTP request-response. So if accessing the collection property happens in a different Hibernate session (read: a different HTTP request), then you will get exaclty this exception.

To fix this, you either need to fetch the collection property eagerly, or to use `Hibernate#initialize()` on the collection property while retrieving the `User`.

#### See also:

- [Hibernate reference documentation - Initializing collections and proxies](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-initialization)

Comment: Thanks. The entity `User` has collections as well as well as single instance variables.(Ex. String name; if I try to call getName(),then it gives exceptions.) I tried to get such variable values not collection's data. Any way you gave me a good point.I ll refere more on your link.Thank you very much once again.

Comment: I'd use `Hibernate#initialize()`. You're storing the instance in the session, so it spans multiple requests. If you're changing the fetch type to eager, then request-based instances of the `User` which are used for different purposes might be too expensive to hold in memory.

Comment: Would you explain a little bit why Hibernate initialize() and advantage.

Comment: If you fetch all properties eagerly, then everytime when you get an `User` instance, it's filled with **all** the data. This is okay when the `User` instance is intented to be stored in HTTP session. But this may cause unnecessary overhead when the `User` instance is intented to be stored in HTTP request (e.g. to show a list of users with only a subset of properties, or to view another user's profile, or to edit an user, etc). However, if you have no such circumstance in your entire webapp, then you may consider to always fetch it eagerly (so that you don't need `Hibernate#initialize()`).

Comment: Thanks BalusC. I read your link as well more. I got a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

That is a problem with lazy loading. Elements which are stored in different database entities (for example a list of child objects) are not loaded directly with the main instance (your userObject), but later when they are really accessed. The advantage is, only objects which are really used have to be loaded from the database.

For loading these extra objects with lazy loading Hibernate needs a session. This is the session which originally was used to load the main instance. This instance is bound to the session. If the session was closed in meantime, you get exactly the error message which you have gotten. For example if you do in this order

```
userObject = session.load(...);
session.close();
userObject.getChildObjects(...); // or whatever the method fetching extra objects is called
```

then you get your error message.

What you can do to avoid this error: For example

- do not close the session
- disable lazy loading in the class mapping for the child objects
- call `userObject.getChildObjects(...);` before you close the session, even if you don't use the fetched objects in that moment.

Storing your main userObject in the HttpSession is principally not a problem, but probably you closed the Hibernate session in meantime while the object was in there.

Comment: Thank you. when I retrieve the User object from Http session, I don't open any Hibernate Session.Then no session to close. Also, I tried to get instance variable (Ex. String name;)not collections.But they also were not available,just gave an exception. Any way I ll try with lazy loading